# Android two way binding Integer type issue

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-viewmodel, two-way-binding

I am having a problem when I want to transfer data from XML to view model class with Int using the data binding method. I've seen many issues related to this, but the solutions I tried haven't been. What is the reason of this?

XML

```
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Telefon"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName2"
        android:text="@={`` +addTenant.tc}"/>
```

View Model

```
class AddTenantVM(application: Application): BaseViewModel(application) {
    val tc = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    fun tenant (){
        println(tc.value.toString())
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share what does the error say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an int, by default, it tries to search for a string resource for the same. (`R.string.example_string` is actually an `int`)

and by putting `` + (int) , the 2-way binding feature is lost - as the binder does not know how to convert it.

Solution:
Put the following code in a separate .kt file (I have created CustomBindings.kt and placed it). No Class needed - just paste the functions directly.

```
@BindingAdapter("my_number")
fun setNumber(view: TextView, value: Int?) {
    if (view.text != value)
        view.text = "" + value
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "my_number")
fun getNumber(view: TextView): Int {
    return view.text.toString().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
}
```

In the XML, remove android:text and put:

```
app:my_number="@={addTenant.tc}"
```

================= Optional Step Below =======================

Also, if you get any error like my_numberAttrChange not defined, put this in CustomBindings.kt

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["my_numberAttrChanged"])
fun setListener(textView: EditText, numberAttrChanged: InverseBindingListener?) {
    if (numberAttrChanged!= null) {
        textView.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, start: Int, end: Int) {
// this will change as per your app's behavourial requirements
                if (start != end) {
                    numberAttrChanged.onChange()
                }
                textView.setSelection(end)
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: this solution worked for me, but I have a problem. When I type an 11-digit number, the number is reset, what could be the problem. (10 digits are okay, but 11 digits are reset by themselves.)

Comment: replace the ```Int``` with ```Long``` in setNumber and getNumber functions. Also, thank you for marking it correct.kindly give an upvote to the answer if this works :)

Answer (score 0):

As your MutableLiveData is Integer type, so edit text is supposed to get integer input type. Try using: `android:inputType="phone"` or `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`.
Also initialize mutable live data in view model. Like this `val tc = MutableLiveData<Int>(0)`